# Выделение поддомена

Tags: url, .htaccess, php

Привет всем!

Нужно выделить поддомен из URL - кто знает как?

Приму как PHP версию, так и htaccess

Есть несколько поддоменов, на них должна стоять одна и таже CMS'ка блога (работающая на xml файлах). Все данные она хранить в папке "content".

Задача: Если домен "1.domain.ru" тогда запрос к данным через /1/content

А если домен "2.domain.ru" тогда запрос к данным через /2/content

Ну это что бы не устанавливать CMS'ку десять раз))

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$array = explode('.', $str);

$array = array_slice ($array, 0, -2);

$array = array_reverse($array);

var_dump($array);
```

Дальше парсите адрес.

Comment: Что-то ничего не получается(( Что не так?
<?php

$str = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domain = parse_url($str);
preg_match_all("/(\w+)/i", $domain["host"], $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$res = array_reverse($arr[0]);
echo "{$res[2]}";

?>

Comment: @Arch1 обновил пост.